# Unknown column 'temp_images' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been wondering why I am encountering this kind of error in mySQL, Can anyone be kind enough to explain to me why I am getting this error?

My problem is that I can't update because of this error

```
Unknown column 'temp_images' in 'where clause'
```

This is the code:

```
function UpdateItem($Item_id, ItemEntity $item) {
        $query = sprintf("UPDATE item_shop
                            SET Name = '%s', Cost = '%d', Description = '%s', Type = '%s', Item_id = '%d', Image = '%s'
                          WHERE Item_id = $Item_id",
                mysql_real_escape_string($item->Name),
                mysql_real_escape_string($item->Cost),
                mysql_real_escape_string($item->Description),
                mysql_real_escape_string($item->Type),
                mysql_real_escape_string($item->Item_id),
                mysql_real_escape_string("/temp_images/" . $item->Images));                 
        $this->PerformQuery($query);
    }
```

Comment: It's easier to debug if you print out the statement $query.

Comment: @Tim3880 the temp_images is actually a file path to get the images

Comment: I understand that. If you print $query you will see there is something wrong , usually with quote marks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but my guess is that `WHERE Item_id = $Item_id` is expanding the `$Item` to the text representation of `$item` rather than `$Item_id`, and so you're getting a whole bunch of junk in your `WHERE` clause.

You want `WHERE Item_id = {$Item_id}`.

Better would be to add `$Item_id` using the same `mysql_real_escape_string` pattern as everything else, which means that you're protected against SQL injection attacks in case you end up with an item ID that is not alphanumeric.